# Node TypeError: Promise resolver #<Promise> is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, aws-lambda

I'm getting a type error on the promise I'm trying to use around the first reject, but from what I can tell it looks like the examples I've found. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var resolve, reject;
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) =>
{

 //var filePromise = new Promise(ProcessFile(resolve, reject));



 var filePromise = new Promise(function ProcessFile()
 {
  console.log("Processing file");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var array;

  if(array.length <0)
  {
   resolve("We have stuff in the array, looks promising");
  }
  else
  {
   reject("Something went wrong populating the array");
  }

  });
 });

 filePromise.then(CheckHeaders());

 function CheckHeaders()
 {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  {
   console.log("Checking headers");
   
   reject("Unauthorised");
  }); //close promise
  } //close function
};
```

Comment: A type error? Are you using typescript? Or do you get a `TypeError` when running the code?

Comment: `filePromise.then(CheckHeaders());` must be `filePromise.then(CheckHeaders);` - `then` expects a function, not a promise.

Answer (score 2):

You only need one promise.

```js
var filePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log("Processing file");
  var array = [1];

  if (array.length > 0) {
    resolve("We have stuff in the array, looks promising");
  } else {
    reject("Something went wrong populating the array");
  }
});

function CheckHeaders() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Checking headers");

    reject("Unauthorised");
  }); //close promise
}

filePromise
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    CheckHeaders()
      .then(res2 => console.log(res2))
  }).catch(err => console.warn(err));
```

As @Bergi pointed out it would be better to only have one overall promise.

```js
var filePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log("Processing file");
  var array = [1];

  if (array.length > 0) {
    resolve("We have stuff in the array, looks promising");
  } else {
    reject("Something went wrong populating the array");
  }

  //here check headers
  reject("Unauthorised");


});

filePromise
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  }).catch(err => console.warn(err));
```

Comment: You should only need one `catch`. Don't nest promises unless you have to.

Comment: I was talking about `filePromise.then(res => {
    console.log(res); return /* sic! */  CheckHeaders(); }).then(res2 => console.log(res2), err => console.warn(err));` not about merging the `filePromise` with the `checkHeaders` promise (although I don't know, it's not clear from the pseudo example code what they would do)